# How to write jQuery traversal function

Tags: javascript, jquery

I want to write a jQuery function called `nextOrPrev()` that works similar to jQuery's `next()` and `prev()`, which returns the next sibling or, in case there isn't any, the previous one. The function should be compatible with jQuery's existing traversal functions like `siblings()`, but also `end()`.

What do I have to write in `$.fn.extend()`?

My attempt was to create an array and then populate it in a `this.each` loop and at the end, return it, but returning that creates a new stack.

Comment: `$.fn.nextOrPrev = function(arg) {var next = this.next(arg); if( next.length) return next; else return this.prev(arg);};` ?

Comment: It should work with multiple matches where each match might or might not have a next element. That is my problem. See https://jsfiddle.net/kL38cy3h/2/ It should be supposed to give me two elements if I pass it two.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Shouldn't be a problem, just write it like any jQuery plugin

```
$.fn.nextOrPrev = function() {
    var args = arguments;
    return $(this).map(function(_,el) {
        var next = $.fn.next.apply($(el), args);
        return (next.length ? next : $.fn.prev.apply($(el), args)).get();
    });
}
```

and use it

```
$('#elem1, #elem2').nextOrPrev()
```

[**FIDDLE**](https://jsfiddle.net/kL38cy3h/6/)

Comment: It doesn't work if you pass it two selected elements, one where there is no next, and one where there is.

Comment: Have a look at https://jsfiddle.net/kL38cy3h/2/ . I would expect `$('#elem1, #elem2').nextOrPrev();` to return a set of two elements, but it doesn't. :(

Comment: Why not? I expect it to give me the next element for `#elem1` (`#toget1`), and the previous element for `#elem2` (`#toget2`). Just like you can call `$("#foo, #bar").next()` and it will give you the next siblings of `#foo` and `#bar`.

Comment: You'd have to iterate to do that, give me a second to change the answer so it returns multiple elements

Comment: My attempt was something along https://jsfiddle.net/vemwpo4a/1/ but that messes up the stack.

Comment: @smares - i've updated the answer, I think that should return the proper chainable jQuery collection in the shortest and easiest way.

Comment: That's it! Thanks a bunch!